# Does stellio-context-broker support keyValues?

Tags: fiware, fiware-stellio

I'm reverse engineering some Stellio data models into fiware's smart model repository and would like to get data out using keyvalues. Is this something Stellio suports?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it is supported, using the standard `options=keyValues` request parameter in your HTTP request (when retrieving an entity or searching for entities).